# Is there in R, a way to make a .txt file with more details than the ones that sink() returns?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Imagine that I have 3 variables `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3`and then I want to print out:

```
a
b
c
a+b
```

When I use `sink()` I get a `.txt` file with this format

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 3
```

but in reality what I want is something like this in order to get traceability of my calculations...

```
[1] a = 1
[1] b = 2
[1] c = 3
[1] a + b = 3
```

I know I can write a string right before the operation and it prints that out in my `.txt` file but imagine that I have too many operations to do that. Is there a way to reproduce this to a `.txt` file?
Thank you!

EDIT: Just saw the `txtStart` function... it seems it can be this. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Certainly possible to get output the way you want, but why not keep the RScript then we know where each calculation is coming from?

Comment: Please don't add random tags: [tag:tidyverse] is rather broad to begin with, and states *"DO NOT USE if your question relates to one or two components of the tidyverse, such as dplyr or ggplot2. Use *those* tags, and tag with `r` as well for a better response."* Further, nothing in your question uses anything non-base.

Comment: Use r-markdown or jupyter.

Comment: Imagine that I want to send the results of my script to someone that knows absolutely nothing of R but knows what "a","b" and "c" means... sending him an RScript will not get the job done

Comment: Please provide realistic example, I doubt anyone would struggle to understand current piece of R code: `a + b`

Comment: It is not a matter of being just a sum... the need here is to understand where the result "3" came from. From "c" or from "a+b"? Like I said, the traceability of the operations displayed is very important for me and a sink() function just give the outputs.